# CSS animation triggers only first time

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, css-animations

I am making a witcher themed page as a side project and have come across a problem. I have made an alchemy page and have all ingredients listed, with all elements that can be extracted beside them. I have made a function that triggers animation with the following logic:
Clicking an ingredient will trigger the animations for the according elements that can be extracted from said ingredient. For example: Fool's parsley can produce Rubedo and Vitriol, upon clicking fools parsley, rubedo shines red and vitriol blue.
My problem is that once an animation is triggered once, it wont trigger again if needed for another ingredient. Example: Fools parsley makes rubedo and vitriol shine, Cadaverine makes rubedo and aether shine. If i click fools parsley, then Cadaverine, when cadaverine is clicked, only aether will shine because rubedo was already triggered once. This also makes clicking the same ingredient twice pointless, as the second time none of the elements will shine.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Alchemy</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="alchemy-page-style.css">
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="alchemy-page.js"></script>




<!--<audio id="source" autoplay loop>
    <source src="C:\Users\user\AngularProjects\The ModernWitcher's Journal\audio\pages\home-page-theme.mp3">
</audio>-->



<div class="container">

    <br>
    <h1 class="homepage-title">
        <img src="../images/witcher-transparent.png"
        class="witcher-transparent-logo">
        Alchemy
        <img src="../images/witcher-transparent.png"
        class="witcher-transparent-logo">
    </h1>
    
    <div class="grid-col">

        <div class="grid-ingredients">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <h2>Herbal Extracts</h2>

                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Allspice_root.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['aether', 'nigredo'])">Allspice root</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Balisse_fruit.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['quebirth', 'rubedo'])">Balisse fruit</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Beggartick_blossom.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['hydragenum', 'rubedo'])">Beggartick blossom</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Berbercane_fruit.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['aether', 'albedo'])">Berbercane fruit</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Bryonia.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['vermilion', 'nigredo'])">Bryonia</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Celandine.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['rebis', 'nigredo'])">Celandine</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Crows_eye.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['vitriol', 'nigredo'])">Crow's eye</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Ergot_seeds.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['vermilion', 'rubedo'])">Ergot seeds</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Feainnewedd.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['vermilion', 'rubedo'])">Feainnewedd</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Fools_parsley_leaves.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['quebirth', 'rubedo'])">Fool's parsley leaves</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Ginatia_petals.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['aether', 'nigredo'])">Ginatia petals</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Green_mold.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['rebis', 'rubedo'])">Green mold</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Han.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['rebis', 'nigredo'])">Han</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Hellebore_petals.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['aether', 'rubedo'])">Hellebore petals</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Honeysuckle.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['quebirth', 'albedo'])">Honeysuckle</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Hop_umbels.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['vitriol', 'nigredo'])">Hop umbels</li>
                    <li
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Mandrake_root.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['quebirth', 'nigredo'])">Mandrake root</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Mistletoe.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['hydragenum', 'nigredo'])">Mistletoe</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Sewants.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['vitriol', 'rubedo'])">Sewant mushroom</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Verbena.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['quebirth', 'albedo'])">Verbena</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/White_myrtle_petals.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['vitriol', 'albedo'])">White myrtle petals</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Wolfs_aloe.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['hydragenum', 'albedo'])">Wolf's aloe leaves</li>
                    <li 
                    style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Wolfsbane.png);"
                    onclick="lightUpElements(['vermilion', 'albedo'])">Wolfsbane</li>
                </ul>

                

        <div class="grid-elements">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <h2>Elements</h2>
                    <li style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/elements/Vitriol.png);" >
                        <span id="vitriol">Vitriol</span>
                    </li>
                    <li style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/elements/Rebis.png);">
                        <span id="rebis">Rebis</span>
                    </li>
                    <li style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/elements/Aether.png);">
                        <span id="aether">Aether</span>
                    </li>
                    <li style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/elements/Quebrith.png);">
                        <span id="quebirth">Quebirth</span>
                    </li>
                    <li style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/elements/Hydragenum.png);">
                        <span id="hydragenum">Hydragenum</span>
                    </li>
                    <li style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/elements/Vermilion.png);">
                        <span id="vermilion">Vermilion</span>
                    </li>
                    <li style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/elements/Albedo.png);">
                        <span id="albedo">Albedo</span>
                    </li>
                    <li style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/elements/Nigredo.png);">
                        <span id="nigredo">Nigredo</span>
                    </li>
                    <li style="list-style-image: url(../images/icons/alchemy/elements/Rubedo.png);">
                        <span id="rubedo">Rubedo</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-descriptions">
            <p id="description"></p>
        </div>

    </div>
    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
let elementList = [];
let color = '';
var i = 0;

const vitriol = document.getElementById('vitriol');
const rebis = document.getElementById('rebis');
const aether = document.getElementById('aether');
const quebirth = document.getElementById('quebirth');
const hydragenum = document.getElementById('hydragenum');
const vermilion = document.getElementById('vermilion');
const albedo = document.getElementById('albedo');
const nigredo = document.getElementById('nigredo');
const rubedo = document.getElementById('rubedo');

function lightUpElements(elementList)
{
for(i = 0; i < elementList.length; i++)
{
    if(elementList[i] == 'vitriol')
    {
        this.vitriol.style.animation = "vitriolShine 0.5s alternate 6";
    }

    if(elementList[i] == 'rebis')
    {
        this.rebis.style.animation = "rebisShine 0.5s alternate 6";
    }

    if(elementList[i] == 'hydragenum')
    {
        this.hydragenum.style.animation = "hydragenumShine 0.5s alternate 6";
    }

    if(elementList[i] == 'quebirth')
    {
        this.quebirth.style.animation = "quebirthShine 0.5s alternate 6";
    }

    if(elementList[i] == 'vermilion')
    {
        this.vermilion.style.animation = "vermilionShine 0.5s alternate 6";
    }

    if(elementList[i] == 'albedo')
    {
        this.albedo.style.animation = "albedoShine 0.5s alternate 6";
    }

    if(elementList[i] == 'nigredo')
    {
        this.nigredo.style.animation = "nigredoShine 0.5s alternate 6";
    }

    if(elementList[i] == 'rubedo')
    {
        this.rubedo.style.animation = "rubedoShine 0.5s alternate 6";
    }

    if(elementList[i] == 'aether')
    {
        this.aether.style.animation = "aetherShine 0.5s alternate 6";
    }
}
}
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
src: url(../fonts/FantaisieArtistique/FantaisieArtistique.ttf);
font-family: witcher;
}

@font-face {
font-family: wonderland;
src: url(../fonts/BeyondWonderland/Beyond\ Wonderland.ttf);
}

@font-face {
font-family: witcher-videogame;
src: url(fonts/WitcherVideogame/Thewitcher-jnOj.ttf);
}

@font-face {
font-family: journal;
src: url(../fonts/Journal/Handwritten_Crystal_v2.ttf);
}

@keyframes elementsFadeIn {
from{opacity: 0;}
to{opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes vitriolShine {
from{opacity: 1;}
to
{
    background-color: rgba(0, 217, 255, 0.507);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
}

@keyframes rebisShine {
from{opacity: 1;}
to
{
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 76, 0.507);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
}

@keyframes aetherShine {
from{opacity: 1;}
to
{
    background-color: rgba(195, 0, 255, 0.507);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
}

@keyframes quebirthShine {
from{opacity: 1;}
to
{
    background-color: rgba(251, 255, 0, 0.507);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
}

@keyframes hydragenumShine {
from{opacity: 1;}
to
{
    background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
}

@keyframes vermilionShine {
from{opacity: 1;}
to
{
    background-color: rgba(109, 74, 0, 0.541);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
}

@keyframes albedoShine {
from{opacity: 1;}
to
{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
}

@keyframes nigredoShine {
from{opacity: 1;}
to
{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.541);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
}

@keyframes rubedoShine {
from{opacity: 1;}
to
{
    background-color: rgba(109, 0, 0, 0.541);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
}

html, body
{
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.container
{
background-image: url(../images/witcher-bestiary-background.jpg);
height: max-content;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
animation: elementsFadeIn 1s;
}

.homepage-title
 {
margin: 0 auto;
font-family: witcher;
font-size: 45px;
color: rgb(189, 0, 0);
animation: elementsFadeIn 2s;
}

.homepage-title .witcher-transparent-logo
{
bottom: 0;
background: rgba(231, 228, 228, 0.342);
border-radius: 5px;
border-style:hidden;
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
animation: elementsFadeIn 3s;
}

.grid-col
{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 300px);
justify-content: center;
padding-bottom: 50px;
margin-top: 5vh;
}

h2
{
font-family: journal;
color: rgb(180, 0, 0);
}

li
{
font-family: journal;
font-size: large;
list-style-position: inside;
justify-content: center;
}

.grid-ingredients
{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(1);
height: max-content;
border: 10px solid transparent;
padding: 0px;
border-image: url(../images/border.png) 70 round;
background-image: url(../images/icons/notebook-clipart-old-writing-paper-5.png);
background-repeat:repeat-y;
background-position: center;
background-size: 120% 120%;
}

.grid-ingredients li:hover
{
cursor: pointer;
}

.grid-elements
{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(1);
top: 0;
position: sticky;
height: max-content;
background-image: url(../images/icons/notebook-clipart-old-writing-paper-5.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: contain;
}
```

Seems like a very basic JS problem but I'm stuck and cant seem to find a workaround. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You know that the above HTML has an unbalanced number of opening/closing `DIV` element tags don't you?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I deleted some content before posting here to make it easier for you to read since it had additional ingredients that werent connected to events and it was pointless to clutter the file with code that is useless to you. The html is fine on my end, this comment is besides the point.

Comment: Also note that an `h2` element is not a valid child of `ul`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly this is not supposed to be a `code restructuring discussion` or problem but there is a way to solve this using the `animationend` event and with the associated callback remove the animation assigned with the click on the Herbal extract.

You'll note that the bulk of this is done with Javascript rather than masses of inline styles and function calls  -it makes it easier (imo) to expand upon and maintain but others may be the judge of that.

The important piece that you could take from this would be the event listener assigned to each Herbal Extract li element - clearly identified below:

```js
const extracts={
    'Allspice root':['aether', 'nigredo'],
    'Balisse fruit':['quebirth', 'rubedo'],
    'Beggartick blossom':['hydragenum', 'rubedo'],
    'Berbercane fruit':['aether', 'albedo'],
    'Bryonia':['vermilion', 'nigredo'],
    'Celandine':['rebis', 'nigredo'],
    'Crow\'s eye':['vitriol', 'nigredo'],
    'Ergot seeds':['vermilion', 'rubedo'],
    'Feainnewedd':['vermilion', 'rubedo'],
    'Fool\'s parsley leaves':['quebirth', 'rubedo'],
    'Ginatia petals':['aether', 'nigredo'],
    'Green mold':['rebis', 'rubedo'],
    'Han':['rebis', 'nigredo'],
    'Hellebore petals':['aether', 'rubedo'],
    'Honeysuckle':['quebirth', 'albedo'],
    'Hop umbels':['vitriol', 'nigredo'],
    'Mandrake root':['quebirth', 'nigredo'],
    'Mistletoe':['hydragenum', 'nigredo'],
    'Sewant mushroom':['vitriol', 'rubedo'],
    'Verbena':['quebirth', 'albedo'],
    'White myrtle petals':['vitriol', 'albedo'],
    'Wolf\'s aloe leaves':['hydragenum', 'albedo'],
    'Wolfsbane':['vermilion', 'albedo']
};
const images={
  'elements':{
    'Vitriol':'../images/icons/alchemy/elements/Vitriol.png',
    'Rebis':'../images/icons/alchemy/elements/Rebis.png',
    'Aether':'../images/icons/alchemy/elements/Aether.png',
    'Quebirth':'../images/icons/alchemy/elements/quebirth.png',
    'Hydragenum':'../images/icons/alchemy/elements/Hydragenum.png',
    'Vermilion':'../images/icons/alchemy/elements/Vermilion.png',
    'Albedo':'../images/icons/alchemy/elements/Albedo.png',
    'Nigredo':'../images/icons/alchemy/elements/Nigredo.png',
    'Rubedo':'../images/icons/alchemy/elements/Rubedo.png',
  },
  'ingredients':{
    'Allspice root':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Allspice_root.png',
    'Balisse fruit':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Balisse_fruit.png',
    'Beggartick blossom':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Beggartick_blossom.png',
    'Berbercane fruit':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Berbercane_fruit.png',
    'Bryonia':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Bryonia.png',
    'Celandine':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Celandine.png',
    'Crow\'s eye':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Crows_eye.png',
    'Ergot seeds':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Ergot_seeds.png',
    'Feainnewedd':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Feainnewedd.png',
    'Fool\'s parsley leaves':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Fools_parsley_leaves.png',
    'Ginatia petals':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Ginatia_petals.png',
    'Green mold':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Green_mold.png',
    'Han':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Han.png',
    'Hellebore petals':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Hellebore_petals.png',
    'Honeysuckle':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Honeysuckle.png',
    'Hop umbels':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Hop_umbels.png',
    'Mandrake root':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Mandrake_root.png',
    'Mistletoe':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Mistletoe.png',
    'Sewant mushroom':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Sewants.png',
    'Verbena':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Verbena.png',
    'White myrtle petals':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/White_myrtle_petals.png',
    'Wolf\'s aloe leaves':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Wolfs_aloe.png',
    'Wolfsbane':'../images/icons/alchemy/ingredients/herbs/Wolfsbane.png'
  }
};

const q=(e,n=document)=>n.querySelector(e);

Object.keys( extracts ).forEach( k=>{
  let li=document.createElement('li');
      li.style.listStyleImage=images.ingredients[k];
      li.textContent=k;
      li.dataset.elements=extracts[ k ];
      li.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        [ ...this.dataset.elements.split(',') ].forEach( element=>{
          let node=q('.grid-elements li[data-name="'+element+'"]');
              node.style.animation=element + 'Shine 0.5s alternate 6';
              /*
                this is what removes the assigned animation
                and prepares it for a new invocation.
              */
              node.addEventListener('animationend', ()=>{
                node.removeAttribute('style');
              });
        });
      });
  q('.grid-ingredients ul').appendChild( li );
});



Object.keys( images.elements ).forEach( k=>{
  let li=document.createElement('li');
      li.style.listStyleImage=images.elements[ k ];
      li.dataset.name=k.toLowerCase();
      
  let span=document.createElement('span');
      span.textContent=k;
  li.appendChild( span );
  
  q('.grid-elements ul').appendChild( li );
})
```

```css
@font-face {
  src: url(../fonts/FantaisieArtistique/FantaisieArtistique.ttf);
  font-family: witcher;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: wonderland;
  src: url(../fonts/BeyondWonderland/Beyond/Wonderland.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: witcher-videogame;
  src: url(fonts/WitcherVideogame/Thewitcher-jnOj.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: journal;
  src: url(../fonts/Journal/Handwritten_Crystal_v2.ttf);
}




@keyframes elementsFadeIn {
  from{opacity: 0;}
  to{opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes vitriolShine {
  from{opacity: 1;}
  to{
    background-color: rgba(0, 217, 255, 0.507);
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
@keyframes rebisShine {
  from{opacity: 1;}
  to
  {
      background-color: rgba(0, 255, 76, 0.507);
      border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
@keyframes aetherShine {
  from{opacity: 1;}
  to
  {
      background-color: rgba(195, 0, 255, 0.507);
      border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
@keyframes quebirthShine {
  from{opacity: 1;}
  to
  {
      background-color: rgba(251, 255, 0, 0.507);
      border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
@keyframes hydragenumShine {
  from{opacity: 1;}
  to
  {
      background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
      border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
@keyframes vermilionShine {
  from{opacity: 1;}
  to
  {
      background-color: rgba(109, 74, 0, 0.541);
      border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
@keyframes albedoShine {
  from{opacity: 1;}
  to
  {
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
@keyframes nigredoShine {
  from{opacity: 1;}
  to
  {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.541);
      border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
@keyframes rubedoShine {
  from{opacity: 1;}
  to
  {
      background-color: rgba(109, 0, 0, 0.541);
      border-radius: 10px;
  }
}




html, body
{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container
{
  background-image: url(../images/witcher-bestiary-background.jpg);
  height: max-content;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  animation: elementsFadeIn 1s;
}

.homepage-title
 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: witcher;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: rgb(189, 0, 0);
  animation: elementsFadeIn 2s;
}

.homepage-title .witcher-transparent-logo
{
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(231, 228, 228, 0.342);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style:hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  animation: elementsFadeIn 3s;
}

.grid-col
{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 300px);
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 5vh;
}

h2
{
  font-family: journal;
  color: rgb(180, 0, 0);
}

li
{
  font-family: journal;
  font-size: large;
  list-style-position: inside;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-ingredients
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1);
  height: max-content;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  padding: 0px;
  border-image: url(../images/border.png) 70 round;
  background-image: url(../images/icons/notebook-clipart-old-writing-paper-5.png);
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 120% 120%;
}

.grid-ingredients li:hover
{
cursor: pointer;
}

.grid-elements
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1);
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  height: max-content;
  background-image: url(../images/icons/notebook-clipart-old-writing-paper-5.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <h1 class="homepage-title">
    <img src="../images/witcher-transparent.png" class="witcher-transparent-logo">
    Alchemy
    <img src="../images/witcher-transparent.png" class="witcher-transparent-logo">
  </h1>

  <div class="grid-col">
    <div class="grid-ingredients">
      <div>
        <h2>Herbal Extracts</h2>
        <ul></ul>   
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="grid-elements">
      <div>
        <h2>Elements</h2>
        <ul></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="grid-descriptions">
      <p id="description"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of the animationend event listener, I have a feeling it is going to be a lifesaver many times to come hahah. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

On the first line of your for statement, try this:

```js
this[elementList[i]].style.animation = "";
```

You need to remove the animation, and then add it again in order for it to start again.

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. I also tried positioning it in different sections(in if statements, sometimes specifically for that element) but it doesnt fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this.

```
animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

Comment: This is not an iteration count problem. Even if the iteration count is 6 it still counts as the animation playing once, it just means it repeats the from-to block 6 times. This did not fix my problem.

Comment: I *highly* recommend explaining *why* this should work; otherwise this is just a comment.